# Limiting Value Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

[image]

Do I just plug in the numbers in the equation and solve like a normal differential equation? I have just started to learn this stuff, and am new to the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

As a physicist, I should prefer to solve the problem for the general case. The integration of the given differential equation is simple and leads to the general formula
$$I(t)=\frac{V \left(1-e^{-\frac{R t}{L}}\right)}{R}$$ This allows later to consider any possible case for which this model applies. For your specific case, this for sure will lead to the value of $5$; however, this $5$ is the ratio of $V$ to $R$ which is a more general result.

Furthermore, having the general formula would allow to analyse the impact of each involved quantity computing for example the derivatives of $I(t)$ with respect to $V$, $R$, $L$ or $t$.

Answer (score 0):

A very routine way is to assume that I(t) settles to a stable value at infinite time, and plug $dI/dt=0$. This gives you $I=5$